# Report Builder- Nested If Statements with Multiple Values to Categorize

Tags: if-statement, reporting-services, reportbuilder, statements

I am working in Report Builder and having issues creating a calculated field to categorize data from another column.

To simplify and explain my goal:

I’d like to create a calculated field with 4 distinct categories and I’m assuming the best way to do that is a nested if statement. Feel free to correct me if that is not the best function to use.

```
Category 1: Let’s just call it “A”
Category 2: “B“
Category 3: “C“
Category 4: “D”
```

Values from the other column:

Simplified Example-

- Numbers 1-10 would be category A,
- numbers 11-20 would be B,
- numbers 21-30 would be C,
- numbers 31-40 would be category D

However in my particular case the values aren’t nicely organized in those 10 consecutive ranges. For example, I have a 33 value that would be an A category, which makes it so I can’t use the greater than or less than operators.

Having explained my issue and goal- my question is how to write the syntax for an if statement when I have multiple discrete values that aren’t neatly organized in consecutive numerical order?

I hope this question makes sense.

I tried using just one argument to get it going and got stumped when it didn’t work:

```
Iif(field data = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,33, “A”, “Other”)
```

It doesn’t work with the commas and I tried inserting the Or Operator between each value and that didn’t work either.

Thanks for any syntax tips you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this.

---

**Option 1: In your database design**

The best way, in my opinion, is to do this in your database. Create a table with these values/category pairs and simply join to that whenever you need to include the categorised view of the data.

---

**Option 2: In your report design**

If you really have to do this in the report design, then using `SWITCH()` will probably be easier, certainly to read.

Given your second example, and expanding it a little you could do something like this...

```
=SWITCH(
        (Fields!myData.Value >=1 AND Fields!myData.Value <=10) OR Fields!myData.Value = 33, "A",
        (Fields!myData.Value >=11 AND Fields!myData.Value <=15) OR Fields!myData.Value = 34 OR Fields!myData.Value = 39, "B",
         True, "Other"
        )
```

SWITCH uses pairs of values, when the first value in the pair evaluates to true the seconds value in the pair is returned.

The final `True, "Other"` acts like an else. If not previous criteria matched, then the final pair always evaluates to true so "Other" would be returned.